# How do I make a custom URL parser with Apache?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, web-config

I heard this can be done with the `web.config` file. I want to make it so, for instance, my URL `http://help.BHStudios.org/site` might go to `http://BHStudios.org/help.php?section=site`, or `http://i.BHStudios.org/u3Hiu` might redirect to some other URL stored in a database with the hash `u3Hiu` as the key, or if something goes wrong and the internal file structure is exposed like `http://Kyli.BHStudios.org/http/bhstudios/v2/self/index.php` (something that happens with GoDaddy's servers for whatever reason) it'll change it to its intended URL `http://Kyli.BHStudios.org` before that's exposed tot he user.

Since I've never done this before, could you please also explain why you gave the answer you did?

Answer (score 3):

A few [Apache mod_rewrite rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/) in either your servers httpd.conf or in a .htaccess file, in your htdocs directory will do the majority of what you want e.g.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase  /

# Default Rule - for non physical objects (not a file or directory): 
# Internally rewrite (user won't see the URL) to /index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]

#If the Browser request contains a .php, instruct the browser to remove it.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}      \.php      [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$       http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1         [R=301,NC,L]

# Specific rule
RewriteRule ^/?site   /help.php?section=site
```

The masking of real file system objects will not be perfect, and slightly pointless, as a user just needs to right click and view source on any served page, to obtain the actual URL's.

Comment: I might not have access to that with GoDaddy; I don't even see an htdocs directory. Will it work if I just create it?

Comment: If you have an Apache based site, then yes, see: https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/2504/what-is-htaccess

Comment: Yes, I have a .htaccess file, but no htdocs directory. What can I do now?

Comment: Per the GoDaddy text, put the file in your root directory.

Comment: Is there anywhere I can safely test this to make sure it doesn't break anything?

Comment: also, I don't quite understand what your code is doing... would it change `http://BHStudios.org/example/index.php` to `http://BHStudios.org/example/index`? That's not what I want...

Comment: Testing, best bet would be to install a copy of Apache on your own PC / Mac.

Comment: goodness that sounds complex... is there a premade sandbox I can download and just run?

Comment: I added your code to `/.htaccess`, but it still doesn't redirect, say https://BHStudios.org/index.php to https://BHStudios.org/

Comment: are you sure it's not just a beautification done by the browser? On my Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Maxthon browsers on my Android phone are showing the URL is unchanged. The same goes for all my desktop browsers.